# Android app crashes when deleting user from firebase Realtimedatabase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am working on my App, and till now the App runs fine despite some small errors. The user can sign in, login and change his profile information. In the last steps, I added a function to delete userinformation. The delete function works so the userinformation gets deleted from FirebaseAuth and the FirebaseRealtimeDatabase but the app crashes.
Before I already had problems with passing null values, maybe thats related to the problem.

Update: I changed the code and tried to implement the suggestions but its still crashing...

Logcat:

```
09-18 16:28:20.474 23342-23342/com.example.login E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.login, PID: 23342
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.login.UserProfil.getVorname()' on a null object reference
    at com.example.login.ProfileActivity$1.onDataChange(ProfileActivity.java:59)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.0.0:75)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.0.0:63)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.0.0:55)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:234)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5526)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Some part of my ProfileActivity

```
 firebaseAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    firebaseDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();



    if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {

        firebaseDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

        final DatabaseReference databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Users").child(firebaseAuth.getUid());

        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
               if (dataSnapshot.exists()) ;
                {
                    UserProfil userProfil = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserProfil.class);
                    profilVorname.setText(userProfil.getVorname());
                    profilNachname.setText(userProfil.getNachname());
                    profilStrasse.setText(userProfil.getStrasse());
                    profilHNr.setText(userProfil.getHnr());
                    profilPlz.setText(userProfil.getPlz());
                    profilStadt.setText(userProfil.getStadt());
                    profilLand.setText(userProfil.getLand());
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "Database Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }else{
        startActivity(new Intent(ProfileActivity.this,NavActivity.class));
    }
```

Some part of my UpdatProfilActivity

```
loeschen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            final DatabaseReference databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Users").child(firebaseAuth.getUid());
            databaseReference.removeValue();
            FirebaseUser user= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

            user.delete().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        // firebaseAuth.signOut();
                        // startActivity(new Intent(UpdateProfilActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                        //finish();
                    }

                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least as a screenshot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete an item from firebase without crashing the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41501805/delete-an-item-from-firebase-without-crashing-the-app)

Comment: thx i added it @AlexMamo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most probably due to that the 'dataSnapshot' object is null when `onDataChange()` is triggered upon deletion; you can return if it is null

```
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (!dataSnapshot.exists())
                return;
            UserProfil userProfil = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserProfil.class);
            profilVorname.setText(userProfil.getVorname());
            profilNachname.setText(userProfil.getNachname());
            profilStrasse.setText(userProfil.getStrasse());
            profilHNr.setText(userProfil.getHnr());
            profilPlz.setText(userProfil.getPlz());
            profilStadt.setText(userProfil.getStadt());
            profilLand.setText(userProfil.getLand());

        }
```

Comment: you could also decide to reset your TextViews instead

Comment: I added the if statement to my code but unfortunately that didn´t help... I get the exactly same error. What do u mean with reset my textviews?

Comment: something weird, your error stops at userProfil.getVorname() with NPE so, userProfil is null which is driven from dataSnapshot object; this may include that datasnapshot object is also null... please debug your code on userProfil.getVorname() ; and see the value of your datasnapshout object.... I mean by resetting to set TextViews to empty text according to your app's behaviour

Comment: As the answer I linked as duplicate indicates, you'll have to use `dataSnapshot.exists` to verify that `dataSnapshot.getValue` does not return null.

Comment: @second I am confused little bit, doc says .exists() Returns true if the snapshot contains a non-null value; how .exists() is called on datasnapshot to check if it's null ... what if it's already null!.. thanks for your input

Comment: I got it.. it's a key/value pair .. this should work .

Comment: @DerHammer123 please have a look at the duplicate post provided by @ second

Comment: thx for your answer... i added the if datasnapshot.exists to my code as in the "duplicate" but the error still occures in the same way :(

Comment: @DerHammer123: Can you update the question / edit the code example with this information?

Comment: @DerHammer123 can you try to remove << firebaseAuth.signOut();                         startActivity(new Intent(UpdateProfilActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                        finish(); >> when you delete the user account; while  keeping check of dataSnapshot.exists()) as agreed earlier; and let me know if the error still exists

Comment: I will update and edit the question now... unfortunately still not working @Zain

Comment: You want to remove that trailing `;` beyond the `if (dataSnapshot.exists())`. If thats not a typo you just terminate the `if block` there.

Comment: Oh thanks so much... just did not see the ; ...somtimes you just get blind whith all that code :)

Comment: @Zain you saved me..after spending whole day,just adding this line solved error of crashing app on deleting user.

Answer (score 1):

When `addValueEventListener` is used, then it listens on every event what happened with current reference. And when you delete it then `dataSnapshot` in listener comes null and on `getVorname()` exception is thrown.

Comment: so what to you think about the second answer would that help with that or do u have another idea maybe?

Comment: Good catch Алексей Юр ;)

Comment: Check on null after trying to get value from snapshot. Doc tells that result may be null. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html#getValue(java.lang.Class%3CT%3E)